# AES - how do I convert a byte-string string to a byte byte-string?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying my hand at AES. I am trying to pass an encrypted message entirely in a procedure:

```
    import hashlib
    import os
    import base64

    from Crypto.Cipher import AES

    IV_SIZE = 16    # 128 bit, fixed for the AES algorithm
    KEY_SIZE = 32   # 256 bit meaning AES-256, can also be 128 or 192 bits
    SALT_SIZE = 16  # This size is arbitrary

    cleartext = b'Lorem ipsum'
    password = b'highly secure encryption password'
    salt = os.urandom(SALT_SIZE)
    derived = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password, salt, 100000,
                              dklen=IV_SIZE + KEY_SIZE)
    iv = derived[0:IV_SIZE]
    key = derived[IV_SIZE:]

    encrypted = salt + AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv).encrypt(cleartext)

    print(encrypted)
    ############################################
    #This is where the examples are being tried
    encrypted = str(encrypted).encode('unicode-escape')
    ###########################################

    encryptedString = base64.encodebytes(encrypted)

    print(encryptedString) 

    encrypted = base64.decodebytes(encryptedString) # <- get the bytes back

    salt = encrypted[0:SALT_SIZE]
    derived = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password, salt, 100000,
                              dklen=IV_SIZE + KEY_SIZE)
    iv = derived[0:IV_SIZE]
    key = derived[IV_SIZE:]
    cleartext = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv).decrypt(encrypted[SALT_SIZE:])

    print(cleartext)
```

I get the following error:  expected bytes-like object, not str

Basically I'm trying to convert a string(byte string) to a byte(byte string). Normally I would pass the string with a b in front of it, like: 
b'?j\xf5\xd3\x8bP\xe5\xd5\xcd\xa2]\xa7\xf7\xc7\x9cO\x92\x0f\xdb}\xf5N\xb94J\xc7\x13'

But in this case the encrypted message will be received as a string and must be converted to bytes.

I have tried:

encrypted = str(encrypted).encode('utf-8')

encrypted = bytes(str(encrypted), 'utf-8')

encrypted = str(encrypted).encode('unicode-escape')

These examples do not yield errors, but the script is encrypting them again instead of decrypting.

Comment: `encrypted = str(encrypted).encode('unicode-escape')` I have no idea what you're trying to do there but it's wrong so get rid of this line. `encrypted = base64.decodebytes(encryptedString)` now that makes some sense if you want to print it out or transmit over a text channel.

Comment: Possibly similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/54142645/5320906

Comment: As James suggested, what happens if you leave out the line altogether? If your base 64 encoder cannot handle byte strings, you may want to use another encoder. The last thing you want is another copy in memory after all.

Comment: So this script is just a redacted version of the full script. There are two separate scripts: a sender and a reader. They both operate independently and the byte object will be captured as a string.

Comment: snakecharmerb is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using snakecharmerb's suggested answer:

```
    import ast
    import hashlib
    import os
    import base64

    from Crypto.Cipher import AES

    IV_SIZE = 16    # 128 bit, fixed for the AES algorithm
    KEY_SIZE = 32   # 256 bit meaning AES-256, can also be 128 or 192 bits
    SALT_SIZE = 16  # This size is arbitrary

    cleartext = b'Lorem ipsum'
    password = input('Password: ')
    password = bytes(password, 'utf-8')
    salt = os.urandom(SALT_SIZE)
    derived = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password, salt, 100000,
                                  dklen=IV_SIZE + KEY_SIZE)
    iv = derived[0:IV_SIZE]
    key = derived[IV_SIZE:]

    encrypted = salt + AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv).encrypt(cleartext)

    print(encrypted)

    ############################################
    encrypted = ast.literal_eval(str(encrypted))
    ###########################################

    encryptedString = base64.encodebytes(encrypted)

    print(encryptedString) 

    encrypted = base64.decodebytes(encryptedString) # <- get the bytes back

    salt = encrypted[0:SALT_SIZE]
    derived = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password, salt, 100000,
                                  dklen=IV_SIZE + KEY_SIZE)
    iv = derived[0:IV_SIZE]
    key = derived[IV_SIZE:]
    cleartext = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv).decrypt(encrypted[SALT_SIZE:])

    print(cleartext)
```