# .encode('utf-8') duplicate backslashes

Tags: python, encoding, byte

I'm making a small script that works with bytes.

I accept some arguments from the cli.

As example:

```py
wrapper.py encode \x50\x90\x51\x91\x52\x92\x53\x93\x54\x94\x55\x95\x56\x96\x57\x97
```

```py
if len(sys.argv)>=3:
    if sys.argv[2]!=None and len(sys.argv[2])==48:
        sys.argv[2]=bytes(sys.argv[2].replace("x",t).encode('utf-8'))
        
        print(sys.argv[2])
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("BAD KEY, KEY must be long 16 bytes")
        sys.exit()
```

I got this as output:

```
b'\\x50\\x90\\x51\\x91\\x52\\x92\\x53\\x93\\x54\\x94\\x55\\x95\\x56\\x96\\x57\\x97'
```

Deleting the encode I cannot do the cast to bytes but I got the correct output:

```py
if len(sys.argv)>=3:
    if sys.argv[2]!=None and len(sys.argv[2])==48:
        sys.argv[2]=sys.argv[2].replace("x",t)
        
        print(sys.argv[2])
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("BAD KEY, KEY must be long 16 bytes")
        sys.exit()
```

Output

```
\x50\x90\x51\x91\x52\x92\x53\x93\x54\x94\x55\x95\x56\x96\x57\x97
```

Comment: You say that you are working with bytes and your first code snippet gives you an output in `bytes`. What more do you need?

Comment: python get `\x50` from command line as normal string with four chars `\x50` not as single char with code `x50` so when you encode it then you get bytes withfour bytes too \, `x`, `5`, `0`, not single byte with code `x50`

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131181/python-3-pycrypto-iv-must-be-16-bytes-long/54142645#54142645

Comment: What is this `t` you replace `'x'` with supposed to be?

Comment: you may need `.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')` to converts string with four chars `\x50` to single char with code `x50` - and then you can encode it to single byte with code `x50`

Comment: t is simply "\\x"

Comment: if you want to work with bytes then replacing `x` is useless - you get raw string - like with prefix `r` in code `r"\x50..."` which has length `64` and if you want to get string with `16` chars then you have to convert `sys.argv[2].encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')` - and it doesn't matter how `print()` displays it becuse it is different problem.

Comment: i'm using as sorta of debug , i know is not the best decision . the decode('unicode_escape) help al lot thanks